# How do I select a mixed group of troops with the Stimpack option showing?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a technique to select an all bio army (marine, marauder, medivac, and ghost) but with the stimpack option available first? Because when I select that army, I get the ghost options first, and I have to tab to select the other army options.

Comment: How are you selecting them? With a click and drag or as an already saved group?

Comment: I always use the saved groups: 1 bio, 2 tank/drop, 3 air/widow.
But for that problem, against protoss, sometimes I need use 1 bio + 2 ghost, to access stim fast, but I lost tank control for quick engagements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is No.

Starcraft has a priority system built-in, and there is no way to modify the priority order.

Ghosts take priority over bio, so if you group your ghosts with the rest of your army you'll have to tab-stim every time.  Because of this you'll likely see ghosts used on a separate hotkey than the rest of the terran army.

The good news is that the stimpack ability takes priority over everything else except the raven's abilities, so omitting ghosts from the control group should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this set up:

1. Marine/Marauder
2. Tanks/Ghosts (depending on which one I have)
3. Medivac (or a drop squad or put Marines/Marauders in the same
   group if controlling all of them at once)
4. All other air
5. CC
6. Any other special hit squad

You usually will have your ghosts and tanks in the back lines, which is why I put them together. Once the tanks are all set up, you can then select a few ghosts at a time to use EMP or Nuke or whatever.

The key is to put your Marine/Marauder in a hotkey set up that is easy to select and easy to manipulate.

You can also set up custom hotkeys in the options menu for each race and each unit. So you may want to try to set up an easier hotkey set up that works well with your general strategies.

Answer (score -1):

You can set it up so the stim option shows up first.
when you select the bio army, press the tab button. This cycles your unit types. Eventually the ghost commands are replaced by the stim command.
once the stim command is showing, set your squad hotkey. That should then be your default squad command.

Comment: While the idea sounds great, this dose not seem to work in practice.